# Count the per Mouse Click and Keyboard Press in Electron MACOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

I created an Electron APP in windows with gkm packages and all functions are working. In MACOS, it needed to allow the app from privacy settings so that the function of the app is working. Is there another way to count the per mouse click and keyboard press of electron app in macOS that not needed to be manually allowed in privacy setting?